# Multiple SparkSessions in single JVM

Tags: apache-spark

I have a query regarding creating multiple spark sessions in one JVM. I have read that creating multiple contexts is not recommended in earlier versions of Spark. Is it true with the SparkSession in Spark 2.0 as well.

I am thinking of making a call to a web service or a servlet from the UI, and the service creates a spark session, performs some operation and returns the result. This will result in a spark session being created for every request from the client side. Is this practice recommended ?

Say I have a method something like :

public  void runSpark() throws Exception {

```
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .master("spark://<masterURL>")
          .appName("JavaWordCount")
          .getOrCreate();
```

and so on....

If I put this method in a web service , will there be any JVM issues ? As such I am able invoke this method multiple times from a main method.But not sure if this is good practice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not supported and won't be. [SPARK-2243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243) is resolved as Won't Fix.

If you need multiple contexts there are different projects which can help you (Mist, Livy).

Comment: Since the question talks about SparkSessions, it's important to point out that there can be multiple `SparkSession`s running but only a single `SparkContext` per JVM.

Comment: Also, if we go by [SPARK-26362](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26362), this was supported before Spark 3.0.0 but now the support has been removed since it causes arbitrary issues.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was accepted. The question was about multiple Spark sessions but not about multiple Spark contexts.

Apparently, there is a way to create multiple sessions like `val newSparkSession = spark.newSession()` but what is still not clear to me is how to close those sessions since `close()` on the session is an alias of `stop()` which stops the context.

Comment: I suspect a session doesn't need to be closed explicitly and will be just removed by the garbage collector when there are no references to it anymore. Probably `clearActiveSession()` should be called to remove it from Spark's thread to the session map. But that is just my guess. Please let me know if someone knows for sure.

Answer (score 18):

The documentation of `getOrCreate` states

> This method first checks whether there is a valid thread-local
>   SparkSession, and if yes, return that one. It then checks whether
>   there is a valid global default SparkSession, and if yes, return that
>   one. If no valid global default SparkSession exists, the method
>   creates a new SparkSession and assigns the newly created SparkSession
>   as the global default.

There is also the method `SparkSession.newSession` that indicates

> Start a new session with isolated SQL configurations, temporary
>   tables, registered functions are isolated, but sharing the underlying
>   SparkContext and cached data.

So, I guess that the answer to your question is, that you can have multiple sessions, but there is still a single `SparkContext` per JVM that will be used by all your sessions.

I could imagine, that a possibly scenario for your web application could be to create one `SparkSession` either per request or, e.g. HTTP session and use this to isolate Spark executions per request or user session **<-- Since I'm pretty new to Spark - can someone confirm this ?**

Comment: I've created another question that is closely related to this one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013542/creating-many-short-living-sparksessions

Answer (score 12):

If you have an existing spark session and want to create new one, use the ***newSession*** method on the existing SparkSession.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
val newSparkSession = spark.newSession()
```

The newSession method creates a new spark session with isolated SQL configurations, temporary tables.The new session will share the underlying `SparkContext` and cached data.

Answer (score 8):

> You can call `getOrCreate` multiple times.

This function may be used to `get or instantiate` a SparkContext and register it as a `singleton` object. Because we can only have one active SparkContext per JVM, this is useful when applications may wish to share a `SparkContext`.

**getOrCreate** creates a `SparkContext` in JVM if there is no `SparkContext` available . If SparkContext is already *available* in JVM it doesn't creates a new but `returns the old one`.