# Spark multiple sessions vs shared global session

Tags: java, apache-spark, configuration, architecture, distributed-computing

### Question

*What is the motivation of creating multiple Spark applications/sessions instead of sharing a global session?*

### Explanation

You have Spark Standalone cluster manager.

Cluster:

- 5 machines
- 2 cores (executors) each = totally 10 executors
- 16 GB RAM each machine

Jobs:

- Dump database, requires all (10) executors, but only 1 GB RAM on each executor.
- Handle dump results, requires 5 executors with 8-16 GB RAM each.
- Quick data retrieval task, 5 executors with 1 GB RAM each.
- etc

***Which solution is a best practice? Why I should ever prefer 1st solution over 2nd, or 2nd over 1st if the resource of the cluster remains the same?***

Solutions:

1. Launch 1st, 2nd and 3rd jobs from different Spark applications (JVMs).
2. Use single global Spark application/session, which holds all resources of the cluster (10 executors, each 8 GB RAM). Create [fair scheduler pool](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#fair-scheduler-pools) for 1st, 2nd and 3rd jobs.
3. Use some hacks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860835/sparkcontext-setlocalproperties) to run jobs with different configs from single JVM. But I'm afraid that's not very stable (officially supported by Spark team if you want) solution.
4. [Spark Job Server][5, but as I understand it's an implementations of the first solution

### Update

Looks like 2nd option (global session with all resources + fair thread pool) isn't possible due to the fact you can configure only number of cores at pool.xml (`minShare`), but can't memory per executor.