# Creating many, short-living SparkSessions

Tags: apache-spark

I've got an application that orchestrates batch job executions and I want to create a `SparkSession` per job execution - especially in order to get a clean separation of registered temp views, functions etc.

So, this would lead to thousands of SparkSessions per day, that will only live for the duration of a job (from a few minutes up to a several hours). Is there any argument to not do this ?

I am aware of the fact, that there is only one `SparkContext` per JVM. I also know that a `SparkContext` performs some JVM global caching, but what exactly does this mean for this scenario ? What is e.g. cached in a `SparkContext` and what would happen if there are many spark jobs executed using those sessions ?

Comment: With jobs between minutes an hours I would just go with an application per job. This way you can fully benefit from all the features of the cluster manager of choice, get reasonable granularity, better control over resources and truly clean state. In general anything that is outside `spark.sql.*` config and Hadoop config cannot be modified on runtime. This include application name, some resource configuration, serializers and so on.

Comment: Hi @Peter, what is your solution to this question? I got similar requirement, but have no idea of the best approach.

Comment: Hello @peter-rietzler,
Thanks for question, Can you add your ans on this I am facing same use case.
I needed to read request from kafka and then create a job as per the request.
So, is this a good idea for creating multiple sessions ?

Comment: @user6502167 can you add your reviews please.

Answer (score 1):

This shows how multiple sessions can be build with different configures

**Use**

**spark1.clearActiveSession();**

**spark1.clearDefaultSession();**

To clear the sessions.

```
 SparkSession spark1 = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("app1")
            .getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> df = spark1.read().format("csv").load("data/file1.csv");
    df.show();
    spark1.clearActiveSession();
    spark1.clearDefaultSession();
    SparkSession spark2 = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .appName("app2")
            .getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> df2 = spark1.read().format("csv").load("data/file2.csv");
    df2.show();
```

For your questions. 
Spark context save the rdds in memory for quicker processing. 
If there is lot of data . The save tables or rdds are moved to the hdd .
A session can access the tables if it saved as a view at any point.
It is better to do multiple spark-submits for your jobs with unique id instead of having different configs.

Comment: By the way, `clearActiveSession` and `clearDefaultSession` are static methods.  So you would actually call like `SparkSession.clearActiveSession()` and `SparkSession.clearDefaultSession()`.