# PySpark scoped temporary view

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

I am using PySpark SQL to create temporary views from dataframes and to make data processing with them.
I created a python service where a user can hit some APIs where they can pass the dataframe and the SQL query to be applied to it to make the data processing.
The problem comes when two users want to use the same name for a temporary view and I was wondering if there's a way to create a scoped temporary view on pyspark. I read that all temporary tables are session-scoped, but it appears to be shared between them.

I've thought of adding prefix the tables with the user name, but it would add extra complexity to the code.

Comment: Spark has "simple" and global temp views, as described in https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-getting-started.html#global-temporary-view. . "Simple" temp views are indeed session-scoped.

Comment: So here's what I tried:
create a session s1 with name 'app1'
create a session s2 with name 'app2'
Create a temp view (non global) using sessions s1
query the view with session s1 -> returns data
query the view with session s2 -> returns data

Comment: `s1 = SparkSession.builder.appName('app1').master(loacal[4]).getOrCreate()
s2 = SparkSession.builder.appName('app2').master(loacal[4]).getOrCreate()
data_json = [{'name': 'myName', 'age': 18}, {'name': 'myName2', 'age': 19}]
df = s1.read.json(s1.sparkContext.parallelize(data_json))
df.createOrReplaceView('myView') # non global
sqlDF1 = s1.sql('select * from myView')
sqlDF2 = s2.sql('select * from myView')`
both return the data in data_json

Comment: SparkSession's static method `getOrCreate` called that for a reason. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153728/multiple-sparksessions-in-single-jvm